# Talents during the time of Achasverous

Tags: money, purim, megillat-esther

The Megillah states that Haman gave 10,000 Talents of silver to King Achasverous.

What is the value of a talent of silver in their age and the value now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14821-weights-and-measures#anchor8) writes a heavy talent was 60 kilograms, a light talent 30 kilograms, and there's an opinion (very bottom) it is 20 kilograms. 10,000 talents would then be between 200-600 tons of silver.

At [today's price](https://www.moneymetals.com/precious-metals-charts/silver-price) of 500 USD/kilo of silver this would be between 100 and 300 million dollars.

The first three sources I found on this topic all concur with the range above ([here](https://frumheretic.blogspot.com/2008/03/10000-talents-of-silver.html), [here](https://www.biblestudytools.com/archive/old-testament/esther-lesson-three-day-3-11566728.html) and [there](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=m787CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=10,000%20talents%20equivalent%20purim%20haman&source=bl&ots=Qv9Q_Xq4sY&sig=ACfU3U2S6T5v8lfsHKXXzQB1wPVpkl2iLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK7ujH--fgAhUBTRUIHZTMC7QQ6AEwDnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=10%2C000%20talents%20equivalent%20purim%20haman&f=false)).

Comment: You wouldn't expect a standard talent to be anything heavier than what one or two strong people could carry; it would be ridiculously unwieldy.

Comment: Like with today's gold ingot which was central banks store, the talent of those days was further broken down in minas (1/60 of a talent) and shekels (1/60 of a mina). Talents were reference units, not what you'd use day to day

Comment: You gave a very "talented" answer!

Comment: 